# Javascript and Css loading after the page loads

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web, twitter-bootstrap

Before you go to website, I want you too look for this. You will notice when the website loads, the first second or two... it display the links in the navbar in a list format, and looks buggy... bc when it finishes loading it looks alright.

website: www.powerliftingbasics.com
This happens every time you refresh/load the page. I use ruby on rails with twitter bootstrap. 
I can't figure it out.

here is my navbar code:

```
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-target=".nav-collapse" data-toggle="collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>
          <a href="/" class="navlogo pull-left"><img src="assets/logosmall.png" alt="Small Logo"></a>
          <a class="brand navfont" href="/">Powerlifting Basics</a>
      <div class="container nav-collapse">
        <ul class="nav pull-right"> 
            <li><%= link_to "Bench Press", "/benchpress"  %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Deadlift", "/deadlift"  %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Squat", "/squat"  %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Equipment", "/equipment"  %></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> more<b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li><%= link_to "Subscribe", "/subscribe"  %></li>
                  <li><a href="mailto:contact@powerliftingbasics.com"> Contact Us</a> </li> 
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul> 
      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your html among other things contains multiples `<head>` and `<body>` so you should start by [checking your page validity (w3.org)](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.powerliftingbasics.com)

Comment: Why down vote of the question, I searched for an answer for a long time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your layouts/application.html.erb
 add application.css and application.js at the top

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>PowerLiftingBasics</title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  </head>
  <body>

    <%= yield %>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: And it will be really better to put `<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>` before closing body tag. Your page will render faster.

Comment: Awesome! this is exactly what i was looking for! Thank you! it was much much appreciated! Why down vote of the question?

Comment: I pressed it was helpful, i can not upvote yet bc i dont have 15 reputation.

Answer (score -1):

It happens cause you placed link to your css files at bottom of page. You should load it before page body. At least, put

```
<link href="/assets/application-65943938be14c000984bcb9478d30563.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

inside `<head></head>` tags.

The best practice is to place css and favicon links in head of page. Javascripts links place at bottom of body (before closing `</body>` tag).

Comment: We never add the css and javascript with the fingerprinting/md5 combination that you have appended.  `rake assets:precompile` does that job of inserting a unique fingerprint

Comment: Do you really understand the difference between html after assets compilation and erb template? ;)

Comment: yes i very well do.. since the guy is working on rails he should know about erb and precompilation :D :)